# ST_DWithin return true but ST_Distance_Sphere not

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I facing out with Postgis.

I've a sql request :

```
SELECT  st_x(ST_Transform(n.geom,4326)) AS x,
                    st_y(ST_Transform(n.geom,4326)) AS y,
                    fetchval(n.tags, 'name') as name,
                    n.id,
                    ST_Distance_sphere(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude), n.geom) as dist
    FROM nodes n
    WHERE ST_DWithin(n.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude),4326), 10)
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude),4326), n.geom)
```

Where :latitude and :longitude is my current location.
In this request I Want to return all nodes in 10 meters around me.

When I dump my results i've got some > 10 meters (the ST_Distance_sphere in SELECT return me nodes > 230 meters of me).

Any ideas of why ?

Thanks.

Comment: ... sample data? also prolly better on [gis.se]

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution,
ST_DWITHIN radius depends of SRID.
If I want it in meters I have to cast my points in meters : 
(::geography)

```
SELECT  st_x(ST_Transform(n.geom,4326)) AS x,
                    st_y(ST_Transform(n.geom,4326)) AS y,
                    fetchval(n.tags, 'name') as name,
                    n.id,
                    ST_Distance_sphere(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude), n.geom) as dist
    FROM nodes n
    WHERE ST_DWithin(n.geom::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude),4326)::geography, 280)
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude),4326), n.geom)
```